# How to remove the entire row in a matrix after another matrix of the same dimension takes a value of 1

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have two matrices:

```
A= [0 0 0 0 1;                     
    0 0 0 1 0;
    1 0 1 0 1;
    0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 1 1 1]

B = [20 15 25 30 40;
     12 15 25 38 24;
     50 23 37 21 19;
      7 20 89 31 41;
     12 13 45 21 31]
```

How to make all the entries in a row of B nan the first time 1 appears in A. in this case I want the output to be:

```
B = [20 15 25 30 Nan;
     12 15 25 Nan Nan;
     Nan Nan Nan Nan Nan;
     7 20 89 31 41;
     12 13 Nan Nan Nan]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

You can use `cummax` or `cumsum` and logical indexing to set the values to NaN:

```
B(logical(cumsum(A,2)))=NaN;
```

or

```
B(logical(cummax(A,2)))=NaN;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution can be using from a loop to consider each row:

```
 for idx = 1 : size(B,1)
     foundOne = find(A(idx,:) == 1);
     B(idx, foundOne:end) = NaN;
 end
```

Answer (score -2):

You want to place NaN in B where there is 1 in the A. It can be simply achieved with one step.

```
A= [0 0 0 0 1;                     
    0 0 0 1 0;
    1 0 1 0 1;
    0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 1 1 1] ;

B = [20 15 25 30 40;
     12 15 25 38 24;
     50 23 37 21 19;
      7 20 89 31 41;
     12 13 45 21 31] ;


 B(A==1) = NaN ;
```

Comment: That's not correct.  Look at the desired `B` matrix carefully.  It does not match your solution.  Look at each row, and as soon as you encounter a `1`, that position and the **rest of the row** should be set to `NaN`.